# python-constraint add dynamic constraint

Tags: python, constraint-satisfaction

I'm using [python-constraint](https://labix.org/python-constraint) library to solve a CSP to reserve bays for each flight in airport. 
Where I need to assign **Bays:**`('A1', 'A2', 'B1', 'B2', 'C1')` to **Flights:**`('MI428', 'UL867', 'QR664', 'TK730', 'UL303')` variables set.

There are few constraints when assigning values to second set. Here is my code

```
from constraint import *

problem = Problem()

flight_names = ['MI428', 'UL867', 'QR664', 'TK730', 'UL303']

bays_list = ['A1', 'A2', 'B1', 'B2', 'C1']

problem.addVariables(flight_names, bays_list)

bay_compat = {'MI428':['A1', 'A2', 'B1'], 'UL867':['B1', 'B2'], 'QR664':['A2', 'B1', 'B2'] , 'TK730':['C1', 'A1'], 'UL303':['B2', 'C1']}

for flight in flight_names:
    problem.addConstraint(lambda fl: fl in bay_compat[flight], [flight])

solutions = problem.getSolutions()

print (solutions)
```

The code above works fine. What I want is to add another constraint where each flight is associated with a particular time period, referred to as time period between arrival and departure times.

For that I created another list as follows:

```
time_constraints = {'MI428':(1,3) , 'UL867':(2,7), 'QR664':(3,9), 'TK730':(15,16), 'UL303':(16,17)}
```

Note: For example, here (1,3) means 1.00 am to 3.00 am

I need bay assignment so that at the same time no two flights gets the same bay. 
So I'm asking how can I add that constraint using `addConstraint()` method in [python-constraint](https://labix.org/python-constraint)??

Comment: In your `time_constraints` the flights have completely disjoint time constraints, which means they are useless because you cannot have any overlapping. Is that what you want?

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta Sorry for that, I fixed it now..

Answer (score 0):

First you have to add variables that define the time at which flights depart:

```
flight_names = ['MI428', 'UL867', 'QR664', 'TK730', 'UL303']
flight_times = ['T-' + name for name in flight_names]
bays_list = ['A1', 'A2', 'B1', 'B2', 'C1']

times = range(20)   # or how many times you have

problem.addVariables(flight_names, bays_list)
problem.addVariables(flight_times, times)
```

Then you have to impose the constraint that each flight must be assigned with a certain time following `time_constraints`:

```
time_constraints = {'T-MI428':(1,3) , 'T-UL867':(2,7), 'T-QR664':(3,9), 'T-TK730':(15,16), 'T-UL303':(16,17)}

for flight_time in flight_times:
    start, end = time_constraints[flight_time]
    problem.addConstraint(lambda fl: fl in range(start, end+1), [flight_time])
```

Now you have to add the "you cannot have two flights at the same bay at the same time" constraints. To do this you need to generate every possible pair of flights:

```
for flight_one, time_one in zip(flight_names, flight_times):
    for flight_two, time_two in zip(flight_names, flight_times):
        if flight_one == flight_two:
            continue
        problem.addConstraint(
            lambda fl_one, t_one, fl_two, t_two: fl_one != fl_two or t_one != t_two, 
            [flight_one, time_one, flight_two, time_two]
        )
```

The constraint is satisfied if **either** the bay used is different **or** the time used is different.

---

<sub>I'm unable to test the code above, however this should give you a good starting point.</sub>

Comment: Is this preserves both constraints?? (compatibility - which I already added & time constraints)

Comment: When I set `time_constraints = {'T-MI428':(1,3) , 'T-UL867':(4,7), 'T-QR664':(8,9), 'T-TK730':(15,16), 'T-UL303':(16,17)}` nothing outputs as the solution.. But there should be solutions right??, since there in no constraint to check at that case

Comment: @VajiraPrabuddhaka Did you change the definition of `times`? The domain `range(10)` was too small and couldn't satisfy the `time_constraints`. The reasoning for the above constraints is sound... now I don't typically use `python-constraint` so there may be an issue/limitations of the library I'm not aware of.

Comment: yeah I changed it to match typical 24-hour time. If you know another way to do this  please inform me. Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52860597/bay-reservation-for-flights) as well.. Thanks for your help..

Comment: @VajiraPrabuddhaka Right not I'm busy. I hope you understood the logic of what I'm saying in my answer: you need a new set of variables that represent the assignment of the flights to the times, and you need a constraint that checks that two different flights cannot be at the same bay at the same time. Alternatively: you could have only the `flight_names` variables, but change the domain from `bays_list` to `[(bay, time) for bay in bays_list for time in times]`. And modify the constraints accordingly (they will now receive a pair instead of just the bay or time.